# Binding `M-ESC M-ESC`

Tags: key-bindings, escape

Attempting to bind `M-ESC M-ESC` in the global map to a command:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-ESC M-ESC") #'my-command)
```

results in the following:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Key sequence M-ESC M-ESC starts with non-prefix key M-ESC ESC")
```

I supposed this is due to [`meta-prefix-char`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Functions-for-Key-Lookup.html) being `ESC` by default, so `M-<char>` gets translated into `ESC-<char>`. Therefore, `M-ESC M-ESC` is `ESC ESC ESC ESC`, and `ESC ESC ESC` is already bound to `keyboard-escape-quit`.

Is there a safe way to separate the `Meta` and `ESC` keys so a binding like `M-ESC M-ESC` is possible? If so, how?

Comment: @Drew What do you mean?

Comment: Done. It's simple: `(global-set-key (kbd "M-ESC M-ESC") #'my-command)`

Comment: This is similar to trying to bind `(kbd "ESC ESC ESC ESC")`, which tells you that `ESC ESC ESC` is not a prefix key. It's not a prefix key because it is not bound to a keymap. See [(elisp) Prefix Keys](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a prefix key because it is not bound to a keymap. See [(elisp) Prefix Keys](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html).

Try this:

```
(define-prefix-command 'foo)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-ESC") 'foo)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-ESC M-ESC") 'forward-char)
```

Comment: Cool, but now `ESC ESC ESC` is no longer bound to `keyboard-escape-quit`.

Comment: Yes. And that's one reason that we don't recommend that you bind `ESC` in such ways. `ESC` is kind of hard-coded to do some pretty important things in Emacs. So while you can rebind things you probably don't necessarily want to do it.

Comment: Does `meta-prefix-char` have a role to play here? Maybe changing it to something else will allow us to bind `M-ESC` to a prefix map and still keep `ESC ESC ESC`?

Comment: Yes, it will, but I don't recommend that. You can certainly try it. But be aware of the consequences. See [(elisp) Functions for Key Lookup](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Functions-for-Key-Lookup.html).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a safe way to separate the `Meta` and `ESC` keys so a binding like `M-ESC M-ESC` is possible? If so, how?

You could bind `<escape>` instead:

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "M-<escape>  M-<escape>") #'my-command)
```

This only works in a GUI frame though.